Convert All Built-in Materials to HDRP stops running
error image
When I run Convert All Built-in Materials to HDRP, loading stops at certain materials.
Even if I turn the project off and on and upgrade it again, it's the same.
[this] (https://i.sstatic.net/VCLi3J7t.png)
Normally, after loading, the material should change from purple to the upgraded material. And it's the same even if you upgrade manually.
P.S.) I have solved it now. The solution was to change the material shader from Legacy to standard. Also, if that doesn't work, change the Varient material to material. Refer to the video below. Refer to the video starting at 5:40. https://youtu.be/nB0r0c-SIVg?si=9-r1_h7GmKHMLRWm

check the space on your system. since hdrp is heavy as compared to other pipelines, it takes more computing power. if your system runs low on memory its the space issue.

When I look at the task manager when I upgrade, the memory space is secured. If the memory is the problem, how can I solve it? Can I solve it by making the pipeline lighter or increasing the computing power? If so, please let me know.

And the error doesn't mention anything about memory issues.
